# Is it possible to stop the first Entry getting Focus in a ScrollView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

In my application I have the following situation:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:NumericTextBoxTest.Converters;assembly=NumericTextBoxTest"
             xmlns:numericTextBox="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfNumericTextBox.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfNumericTextBox.XForms"
             x:Class="NumericTextBoxTest.MainPage">
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>    
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
    </StackLayout>

  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Now If I click the blank space at the bottom (below the entries) i.e. the `ScrollView` the first `Entry` in the `ScrollView` will gain focus.

Very annoying If I am changing the value on the first `Entry` and trying to unfocus that `Entry` to set the value.

Is it possible to stop this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "gain focus"? Can you maybe add an image of the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: try to add a hidden control and set focus to it :)

Comment: @Krumelur It's difficult to show what I mean with an image. But basically the top Entry always has the cursor in it and is ready for you to type an input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I actually ended up overriding the default `ScrollViewRenderer` as mentioned in this comment:

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/597#issuecomment-513804526

My `ScrollViewRenderer` on UWP looked like this:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using ScrollBarVisibility = Xamarin.Forms.ScrollBarVisibility;
using UwpScrollBarVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollBarVisibility;
using Size = Xamarin.Forms.Size;
using Point = Xamarin.Forms.Point;
using Thickness = Xamarin.Forms.Thickness;
using FieldStrikeMove.Forms.CustomControls;

//https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/597

//https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/f17fac7b9e2225b1bfe9e94909d2b954106f8f1f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/ScrollViewRenderer.cs
//07/01/20

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedScrollView), typeof(MyApp.UWP.CustomRenderers.Controls.ScrollViewRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollView), typeof(MyApp.UWP.CustomRenderers.Controls.ScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace MApp.UWP.CustomRenderers.Controls
{
    public class ScrollViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<ScrollView, ScrollViewer>//, IDontGetFocus
    {
        VisualElement _currentView;
        bool _checkedForRtlScroll = false;

        public ScrollViewRenderer()
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }

        public override SizeRequest GetDesiredSize(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            SizeRequest result = base.GetDesiredSize(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
            result.Minimum = new Size(40, 40);
            return result;
        }

        protected override Windows.Foundation.Size ArrangeOverride(Windows.Foundation.Size finalSize)
        {
            if (Element == null)
                return finalSize;

            Element.IsInNativeLayout = true;

            Control?.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height));

            Element.IsInNativeLayout = false;

            return finalSize;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            CleanUp(Element, Control);
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        protected override Windows.Foundation.Size MeasureOverride(Windows.Foundation.Size availableSize)
        {
            if (Element == null)
                return new Windows.Foundation.Size(0, 0);

            double width = Math.Max(0, Element.Width);
            double height = Math.Max(0, Element.Height);
            var result = new Windows.Foundation.Size(width, height);

            Control?.Measure(result);

            return result;
        }

        void CleanUp(ScrollView scrollView, ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
        {
            if (Element != null)
                Element.PropertyChanged -= OnContentElementPropertyChanged;

            if (ContainerElement != null)
                ContainerElement.LayoutUpdated -= SetInitialRtlPosition;

            if (scrollView != null)
            {
                scrollView.ScrollToRequested -= OnScrollToRequested;
            }


            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                scrollViewer.ViewChanged -= OnViewChanged;
                if (scrollViewer.Content is FrameworkElement element)
                {
                    element.LayoutUpdated -= SetInitialRtlPosition;
                }
            }

            if (_currentView != null)
                _currentView.Cleanup();
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ScrollView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            CleanUp(e.OldElement, Control);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    SetNativeControl(new ScrollViewer
                    {
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibilityToUwp(e.NewElement.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility),
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibilityToUwp(e.NewElement.VerticalScrollBarVisibility),
                    });

                    Control.ViewChanged += OnViewChanged;
                }

                Element.ScrollToRequested += OnScrollToRequested;

                UpdateOrientation();

                UpdateContent();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "Content")
                UpdateContent();
            else if (e.PropertyName == Layout.PaddingProperty.PropertyName)
                UpdateContentMargins();
            else if (e.PropertyName == ScrollView.OrientationProperty.PropertyName)
                UpdateOrientation();
            else if (e.PropertyName == ScrollView.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty.PropertyName)
                UpdateVerticalScrollBarVisibility();
            else if (e.PropertyName == ScrollView.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty.PropertyName)
                UpdateHorizontalScrollBarVisibility();
        }

        protected void OnContentElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == View.MarginProperty.PropertyName)
                UpdateContentMargins();
        }

        void UpdateContent()
        {
            if (_currentView != null)
                _currentView.Cleanup();

            if (Control?.Content is FrameworkElement oldElement)
            {
                oldElement.LayoutUpdated -= SetInitialRtlPosition;

                if (oldElement is IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer
                    && oldRenderer.Element is View oldContentView)
                    oldContentView.PropertyChanged -= OnContentElementPropertyChanged;
            }

            _currentView = Element.Content;

            IVisualElementRenderer renderer = null;
            if (_currentView != null)
                renderer = _currentView.GetOrCreateRenderer();

            Control.Content = renderer != null ? renderer.ContainerElement : null;

            UpdateContentMargins();
            if (renderer?.Element != null)
                renderer.Element.PropertyChanged += OnContentElementPropertyChanged;

            if (renderer?.ContainerElement != null)
                renderer.ContainerElement.LayoutUpdated += SetInitialRtlPosition;
        }

        async void OnScrollToRequested(object sender, ScrollToRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            ClearRtlScrollCheck();

            // Adding items into the view while scrolling to the end can cause it to fail, as
            // the items have not actually been laid out and return incorrect scroll position
            // values. The ScrollViewRenderer for Android does something similar by waiting up
            // to 10ms for layout to occur.
            int cycle = 0;
            while (Element != null && !Element.IsInNativeLayout)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
                cycle++;

                if (cycle >= 10)
                    break;
            }

            if (Element == null)
                return;

            double x = e.ScrollX, y = e.ScrollY;

            ScrollToMode mode = e.Mode;
            if (mode == ScrollToMode.Element)
            {
                Point pos = Element.GetScrollPositionForElement((VisualElement)e.Element, e.Position);
                x = pos.X;
                y = pos.Y;
                mode = ScrollToMode.Position;
            }

            if (mode == ScrollToMode.Position)
            {
                Control.ChangeView(x, y, null, !e.ShouldAnimate);
            }
            Element.SendScrollFinished();
        }

        void SetInitialRtlPosition(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (Control == null) return;

            if (Control.ActualWidth <= 0 || _checkedForRtlScroll || Control.Content == null)
                return;

            if (Element is IVisualElementController controller && controller.EffectiveFlowDirection.IsLeftToRight())
            {
                ClearRtlScrollCheck();
                return;
            }

            var element = (Control.Content as FrameworkElement);
            if (element.ActualWidth == Control.ActualWidth)
                return;

            ClearRtlScrollCheck();
            Control.ChangeView(element.ActualWidth, 0, null, true);
        }

        void ClearRtlScrollCheck()
        {
            _checkedForRtlScroll = true;
            if (Control.Content is FrameworkElement element)
                element.LayoutUpdated -= SetInitialRtlPosition;
        }

        void OnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ClearRtlScrollCheck();
            Element.SetScrolledPosition(Control.HorizontalOffset, Control.VerticalOffset);

            if (!e.IsIntermediate)
                Element.SendScrollFinished();
        }

        Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness AddMargin(Thickness original, double left, double top, double right, double bottom)
        {
            return new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(original.Left + left, original.Top + top, original.Right + right, original.Bottom + bottom);
        }

        // UAP ScrollView forces Content origin to be the same as the ScrollView origin.
        // This prevents Forms layout from emulating Padding and Margin by offsetting the origin. 
        // So we must actually set the UAP Margin property instead of emulating it with an origin offset. 
        // Not only that, but in UAP Padding and Margin are aliases with
        // the former living on the parent and the latter on the child. 
        // So that's why the UAP Margin is set to the sum of the Forms Padding and Forms Margin.
        void UpdateContentMargins()
        {
            if (!(Control.Content is FrameworkElement element
                && element is IVisualElementRenderer renderer
                && renderer.Element is View contentView))
                return;

            var margin = contentView.Margin;
            var padding = Element.Padding;
            switch (Element.Orientation)
            {
                case ScrollOrientation.Horizontal:
                    // need to add left/right margins
                    element.Margin = AddMargin(margin, padding.Left, 0, padding.Right, 0);
                    break;
                case ScrollOrientation.Vertical:
                    // need to add top/bottom margins
                    element.Margin = AddMargin(margin, 0, padding.Top, 0, padding.Bottom);
                    break;
                case ScrollOrientation.Both:
                    // need to add all margins
                    element.Margin = AddMargin(margin, padding.Left, padding.Top, padding.Right, padding.Bottom);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void UpdateOrientation()
        {
            //Only update the horizontal scroll bar visibility if the user has not set a desired state.
            if (Element.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility != ScrollBarVisibility.Default)
                return;

            var orientation = Element.Orientation;
            if (orientation == ScrollOrientation.Horizontal || orientation == ScrollOrientation.Both)
            {
                Control.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = UwpScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            }
            else
            {
                Control.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = UwpScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
            }
        }

        UwpScrollBarVisibility ScrollBarVisibilityToUwp(ScrollBarVisibility visibility)
        {
            switch (visibility)
            {
                case ScrollBarVisibility.Always:
                    return UwpScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
                case ScrollBarVisibility.Default:
                    return UwpScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
                case ScrollBarVisibility.Never:
                    return UwpScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
                default:
                    return UwpScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            }
        }

        void UpdateVerticalScrollBarVisibility()
        {
            Control.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibilityToUwp(Element.VerticalScrollBarVisibility);
        }

        void UpdateHorizontalScrollBarVisibility()
        {
            var horizontalVisibility = Element.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility;

            if (horizontalVisibility == ScrollBarVisibility.Default)
            {
                UpdateOrientation();
                return;
            }

            var orientation = Element.Orientation;
            if (orientation == ScrollOrientation.Horizontal || orientation == ScrollOrientation.Both)
                Control.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibilityToUwp(horizontalVisibility);
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        internal static void Cleanup(this VisualElement self)
        {
            if (self == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("self");

            IVisualElementRenderer renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(self);

            foreach (Element element in self.Descendants())
            {
                var visual = element as VisualElement;
                if (visual == null)
                    continue;

                IVisualElementRenderer childRenderer = Platform.GetRenderer(visual);
                if (childRenderer != null)
                {
                    childRenderer.Dispose();
                    Platform.SetRenderer(visual, null);
                }
            }

            if (renderer != null)
            {
                renderer.Dispose();
                Platform.SetRenderer(self, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Setting IsTabStop to true doesn't do anything. This works! So the problem is IDontGetFocus interface! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm seeing the same (or a very similar) problem on Xamarin.Forms app on iOS, but this solution isn't applicable. Has anyone solved the problem for iOS?

Comment: @CMPalmer I haven't seen it on iOS, although I must admit I haven't tested later XF versions on iOS. I would take a look at the [Xamarin.Forms github issues](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) to see if anyone else has an issue there

Answer (score 8):

> Now If I click the blank space at the bottom (below the entries) i.e. the ScrollView the first Entry in the ScrollView will gain focus.

In UWP it is by design that when the `StackLayout` gets tapped the system will search element for-each in the `StackLayout` until the first one which can be focused on. As a workaround to solve this issue, you can place an invisible buton in the top of `StackLayout`.

```
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button HeightRequest="0" WidthRequest="1" />
            <Entry  />
            ....
            <Entry />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

The button will be focused on when `StackLayout` was tapped. The `Entry` will not be focused

Comment: So this is the UWP platform behaving like this, not `Xamarin.Forms`? It was providing a very bad UX for my users. I will try your workaround and let you know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The workaround works well. Annoying an invisible button needs to be added to the `View` to stop this behavior

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works: I don't like very much this solution, but that's it. Why the hell StackLayout behaves like that?!

Comment: It doesn't work. Yes, the button is focused instead of entry but if you scroll a little down in ScrollView and then click somewhere where no element or non-focusable element is present, it scrolls to the top! @user1 answer works!

Answer (score 0):

> If I click the blank space at the bottom (below the entries)

you can stretch your stacklayout and then it will receive focus instead scrollview.

And you can also set backgroundcolor for stacklayout to make sure that stacklayout is stretched

Answer (score 0):

[Update]

I just found out that I really needed to fully qulify the Namespace of my custom `ScrollViewRenderer` for the `Target` Parameter of the `ExportRenderer` Atrribute when the Class has the same Name as the one from Xamarin Forms.

Now it's working as expected

[Original]

I tried implementing the CustomRenderer posted by User1 but it seems like it is not used in the UWP Project. The Constructor of the `ScrollViewRenderer` is never called although I have a `ScrollView` on the Page.

If I derive a `CustomScrollView` from `ScrollView` and let the Renderer be applied to `CustomScrollView` it is used and the workaround is working as expected but it seems I'm not able to override the Renderer for all ScrollViews.

Any hint why the renderer isn't used to replace the default builtin ScrollViewRenderer of XF? (btw. I'm using XF 5.0.0.1874)

Answer (score 0):

In MAUI applications workaround with adding fake button works well. I don't like it so much as well, but it's quick and simple solution without having to figure out with ScrollViewRenderer from another comments from this topic.