# Is there a way to prevent a Xamarin Forms scrollview from automatically scrolling to the last edited Entry when a picker control is opened?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a setup similar to this:

```
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>    
      <Entry/>
      <Picker/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Picker/>
      <Picker/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
      <Entry/>
    </StackLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

Where the Entry and Picker controls are dynamically created and modified. The problem is that if I type into an Entry and then open one of the Picker controls, the ScrollView scrolls to where the previously edited Entry is in view. It was getting focus, but I prevented the focus from shifting, yet the ScrollView scrolls and I can't seem to prevent it.

I did something similar to [Is it possible to stop the first Entry getting Focus in a ScrollView in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231163/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-first-entry-getting-focus-in-a-scrollview-in-xamarin#) to fix the related issue in UWP, but that solution is not applicable to iOS and Android.

Comment: I created the project with xaml. I typed into an Entry and then open one of the Picker controls, the ScrollView did not scroll to where the previously edited Entry is in view. You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/o3sS039 Could you provie more details for me?

Comment: You could try the code in the reply to reset the focuse. And could you provid your device version and xamarin.form version?

Answer (score 1):

Set the name of `StackLayout`. Foreach the elements in 'StackLayout' and reset the focus.

```
 private void Picker_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in stackLayout.Children)
        {
            if (sender!=item)
            {
                item.Unfocus();                   
            }              
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still scrolls to the control, even if it doesn't get focus. I'd tried this before, but I tried it again for completeness sake. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: The scrolling happens *after* the picker's Focus event fires and completes.